# If the caster of the Unseen Servant spell is more than 60 feet away when giving a command, or when the Unseen Servant attempts a task, what happens?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, summoning

The only mention of the *[Unseen Servant](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Unseen%20Servant#content)* spell ending due to distance from the caster is found at the end of its description:

> If you command⁠ the servant to perform a task that would move it more
> than 60 feet away from you, the spell ends.

Compare this to a similar, but lower-level spell, *[Mage Hand](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Mage%20Hand#content)*, which includes the following in its description:

> The hand vanishes if it is ever more than 30 feet away from you

Say an unseen servant is spawned in a location where it can complete a task without moving. Will the spell end if the caster commands it to do the task while being more than 60 feet away from the servant?

Similarly, say an unseen servant is spawned in a location where it can complete a task without moving. The caster, while within 60 feet of it, commands it to do the task at a predetermined time in the future (e.g. "1 minute from now", or "once I cross this bridge"). If the caster is then 60 feet or more away when the time comes to do the task, will the spell end?

*Unseen Servant*'s spell description of what it is capable of doing and how it does it:

> The servant can perform simple tasks that a human servant could do,
> such as fetching things, cleaning, mending⁠, folding clothes, Lighting
> fires, serving food, and pouring wine. Once you give the command⁠, the
> servant performs the task to the best of its ability until it
> completes the task, then waits for your next command⁠.

In both scenarios, I think the Unseen Servant is able to complete the task without the spell ending. My reasoning for this is the specific wording of "that would move it more than 60 feet away from you", a wording not found, as far as I know, in many (any?) other spells, & the glaring lack of anything along the lines of the quoted portion of *Mage Hand*'s description, a version of which is found in numerous spell descriptions.

In the second scenario specifically, I think the task is completed without the spell ending for an additional reason, which is that the task starts once the command is given & waiting for the appropriate trigger is, mechanically, the first part of a two-part task.

I would really appreciate hearing the community's thoughts on this one.

---

I did read a similar *Unseen Servant* question which has offered some insight:
[Does the Unseen Servant spell end if I move away from it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/145534/does-the-unseen-servant-spell-end-if-i-move-away-from-it)

However, it doesn't quite cover everything I've put forward. The three scenarios presented in the other question do not cover the same mechanics as mine. Receiving a command from more than 60 feet away - theirs involves the Servant moving; mine does not. Having the caster move more than 60 feet away away after issuing a command is only mechanically similar if the task is, as I laid out in my example, a 'two-part task'. Certainly, the two questions are similar, but the specifics presented are not the same.

Comment: We can't know what the designers thought when wording their spell - which is why Rules as Intended are generally opinion based.

Comment: I am not clear why all the downvotes for this question. I've +1'd it, because I think it pokes at some interesting points.  However, I think it would improve by drastic simplification.  It's actually asking 2 different questions.

Comment: Your question post should be focused on your question(s) alone. You should edit out the portion of your post where you attempt to answer your own question(s), and post that as an answer to the question instead. See this help center article for reference (and the blog post it links to): [Can I answer my own question?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: You point out that your question is subtly different from that other one, but it is very similar: both are about the peculiar wording of *Unseen Servant*, that allows the servant to perform tasks out of your immediate 60 foot range, where other spells like *Mage Hand* end when the effect is at a greater distance than specified in the spell at any time. You even provide your own, well-documented answer to your question.

Answer (score 8):

The way the spell is worded, the servant will do these tasks without the spell ending, for both cases. In neither case is the servant receiving a command to do something that will *move it* more than 60 feet away from the caster. As outlined in the answer to [the other, similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/145534/does-the-unseen-servant-spell-end-if-i-move-away-from-it), that the servant is farther away than 60 feet from the caster while it is performing its tasks will not end the spell.

One can critique the wording of *Unseen Servant* for many things that are unclear, but this particular element is an elegant way to allow the caster to command his servant to do the dishes, then take off into the city, while at the same time making it hard for the caster to abuse the servant to avoid getting close to danger himself, as he has to cast it from within 60 feet of it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.